# Can't update Assembly version

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have this class library called CarLibrary. I modified some code and changed the assembly version in project property "Assembly information"  from 1.0 to 2.0 but when I build the CarLibrary, I can not see the new assembly version 2 in debug/bin folder, it's always version 1, what could have been wrong?

Comment: Your build failed, or your output directory is different from the one you're looking at.

Comment: it didn't fail for sure , i can see the output message, it says 1 up-to-date,and output path set to bin\Debug\

Comment: So how do you *actually* look at the version number?  It is not easy to see, Explorer does not display it all.

Comment: just hover the mouse over assembly and there is a pop up message says  file version: 1.0.0.0

Comment: oh yeah you are right , its file version not assembly version , my mistake, thank you

Answer (score 0):

### Changing Assembly Version

In Visual Studio, the assembly Version can be set via UI by the following steps:

- Open `CarLibrary` Properties (right click on project)
- In Properties Tab:

  - *Application > Assembly Information*
  - Set ´Assembly version´ and ´File version´ to any value.

However you may also modify this manually. Just open ´CarLibrary/Proerties/AssemblyInfo.cs´. Change the following Attributes:

```
// Use any number you want
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.2.3.444")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.2.3.444")]
```

### If this doesn't work

If the Changes won't be applied, it could be one of this reasons:

- You are building the wrong Build-Configuration e.g. ´Release´ instead of ´Debug´
- You have Compilation errors

  - Be sure by performing *Build > Clean Solution* and *Build > Rebuild Solution*
- Anyway ensure that `CarLibrary´ is really built during this process, by reading the *Output*